# javascript and php variables exchange

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

would be possible to pass javascript variable to php and execute function on it and convert it back to javascript

what I want is to get the value on click of an input field and deocode and pass it back

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.my_id').click(function(){
    var lv = $('div.special_box form input').val();
    var lv = <?php base64_decode( 'here should come my javascript variable' )?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript runs in the browser and php on the server. So you would have to make a server request. You should search for `ajax`.

Comment: No. Javascript runs on the client. PHP runs on the server. You'll need to use AJAX calls.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback than I'm going to use ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it as you are asking above.  Javascript is a client side language, php a server side language.  While there are other methods, you should use AJAX to call a separate page that will simply return the value from the function.

```
lv = $.ajax({
    url: "some.php?lv=" + lv,
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

Comment: Just for clarification, the php-file must echo out the result. this solution works fine if you only want ONE return-value.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld is correct, although if you needed multiple values, you could always return a parsable string or XML.